# Infinity Files python

Tags: python

I need a programm that could generate infinity files this is what I done yet

```
x = 1

V = "Test"

while True:
    str(x)

    text = x,".txt"

    f = open(text, "w")
    f.write(V)
```

x += 1

but when I start it the Errorcode is

```
line 26, in <module>
    f = open(text, "w")
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
```

or

[WinError 6]

and i don't understand why because I convert x to a string .

Comment: `x` is a string, `text = x,".txt"` is a tuple

Comment: Also, you should close your file or you will incur into too many open file problems.

Comment: @BtcSources or just use a context manager (`with`); also the `x += 1` is out of the `while` loop block

Comment: Although, in CPython, reference counting will close most of them

Comment: "and i don't understand why because I convert x to a string ." But you aren't passing `x`, you are passing `text`, and text is very obviously a tuple: `text = x,".txt"` try it out for yourself in the repl

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate the values together. Using a comma creates a tuple, which is not what you want.

```
text = str(x) + ".txt"
# or
text = f'{x}.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `with open(filename, mode) as hanlder` so that
the the file stream gets closed and garbage collected after each file
operation:

Also you forgot to increment x and there's no need to type cast x to str

```
x = 1

V = "Test"

while True:

    text = f"{x}.txt"

    with open(text, "w") as f:
      f.write(V)
    x += 1
```